# Kubernetes - Granting RBAC access to anonymous users in kube dns

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kube-dns

I have Kubernetes Cluster setup with a master and worker node. 
Kubectl cluster-info shows kubernetes-master as well as kube-dns running successfully.

I am trying to access below URL and since it is internal to my organization, below URL is not visible to external world.

https://10.118.3.22:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

But I am getting below error when I access it -

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kube-dns:dns\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"services/proxy\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kube-system\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "kube-dns:dns",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Please let me know how to grant full access to anonymous user. I read RBAC mentioned in https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/
But unable to figure out what exactly I need to do. Thanks

Comment: How do you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

You can grant the admin privileges to the anonymous user, but I strongly strongly discourage it. This will give anyone outside the cluster access to the services using the url.

Even after that you decided to grant all the access to the anonymous user you can do it following way:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: anonymous-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["services/proxy"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: anonymous-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: anonymous-role
subjects:
- apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: User
  name: system:anonymous
```

This will give anonymous:user to proxy your services, not all resources. If you want that for all resources you need to provide `resources: ["*"]` in anonymous-role.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am sorry am a newbie but where should I provide this?

Comment: You need to copy paste that in a file and run that file as `kubectl create -f file.yaml`

Comment: Did that.. but now it is showing this - Error: 'EOF'  Trying to reach: 'http://10.244.0.5:53/'

Comment: https://10.118.3.22:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/  page is showing "message": "services is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list resource \"services"\ in API group \"\" in the namespace "\kube-system\""

Comment: I also have the same problem. Anything new on this?