# How to resolve dns problem in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kube-dns

I've a very strange error in my kubernetes configuration.
When I'm trying to connect to KubeDNS (I'm using minikube) I have the following error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kube-dns:dns\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"services/proxy\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kube-system\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "kube-dns:dns",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

I read something about RCAD but I can't find anything that explaine clearly what must I do.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kubernetes - Granting RBAC access to anonymous users in kube dns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54154112/kubernetes-granting-rbac-access-to-anonymous-users-in-kube-dns)

Comment: @hoque I just red this answer but as you can see is "very discouraged" for eventually security problem

Comment: how do you try to connect kube dns? from pod?

Comment: @hoque I use kubectl cluster-info and after I copied and paste in Google Chrome simply

Comment: run `kubectl proxy` and replace the adress `<ip>:<port>` then check

Comment: @Alex - did you find a solution to this. I am facing same issue when using minikube

Comment: yes, the solution is: don't use minikube!! if you want to practise in kubernetes use katakoda or google cloud solution!